# Aligning sub-equations within align

Tags: amsmath, align

### Update:

How do I align both the `\sum` signs and the `=` signs in the last two equations? I have updated the picture.

### Original Question:

When I use the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \label{eq:BILP}
    \mathpzc{I}^* & = \argmax_{\mathcal{I}} \; \left\{\sum_{i\in \mathcal{V}} \left(\theta_K \cdot \mathbb{I}_{i,j}(1,1) + \theta_K \cdot \mathbb{I}_{i,j}(0,0) \right) + \right.\\
    & \qquad  \qquad \quad \;\,\;\; \left. \sum_{i\in \mathcal{E}} \theta_{i_0} \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_i=0) + \theta_{i_1} \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_i=1) \right\}\\
    & \qquad \qquad  \text{s.t.} \; \; \sum_{x_j} \mathbb{I}_{i,j}(1,x_j)  =   \mathbb{I}(x_i=1) \\
    & \qquad \qquad  \qquad \sum_{x_i}\mathbb{I}_{i,j}(x_i,1) =   \mathbb{I}(x_j=1) \\
    & \qquad \qquad  \qquad \sum_{x_i,x_j}\mathbb{I}_{i,j}(x_i,x_j) = 1 \\
    %& \;\psi_{\mathrm{SAT}}\left(\mathbf{s}, \mathbf{l}\right) = 1
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
```

I get the following (note the misalignment between the `\sum` signs, and the `=` signs highlighted under the red lines):

[image]

How can I get them to align? (and avoid using all the artificial `\qquad`, `\,` `\;` spaces)

Comment: Are you maybe missing a pair of parentheses around the argument of the summation on the second line? Just curious.

Comment: You are right @Mico. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `\bigg` variety for bigger delimiters and align the sums. There's a subtlety for the last one, since the long subscript would shift it to the right and `\mathclap` from `mathtools` avoids it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:BILP}
\begin{split}
I^* = \argmax_{\mathcal{I}}\biggl\{
  & \sum_{i\in \mathcal{V}} (\theta_K \cdot \mathbb{I}_{i,j}(1,1) + \theta_K \cdot \mathbb{I}_{i,j}(0,0) ) + {}\\
  & \sum_{i\in \mathcal{E}} \theta_{i_0} \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_i=0) + \theta_{i_1} \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_i=1) \biggr\}\\
\text{s.t.}\quad
  & \sum_{x_j} \mathbb{I}_{i,j}(1,x_j)  = \mathbb{I}(x_i=1) \\
  & \sum_{x_i}\mathbb{I}_{i,j}(x_i,1) = \mathbb{I}(x_j=1) \\
  & \sum_{\mathclap{x_i,x_j}}\mathbb{I}_{i,j}(x_i,x_j) = 1 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the "starred" version of the `\DeclareMathoperator` macro would under-set rather than side-set the `\mathcal{I}` element. :-)

Comment: @Mico I didn't notice that; thanks.

Comment: +1 `mathtools` loads `amsmath` so there's no need to load both explicitly

Comment: The `\mathclap` part can also be done via the `\smashoperator` in `mathtools`

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I'm wondering if there is a way of getting two things aligned vertically, the `\sum` signs and the `=` on the last three equations?

Comment: @roseck I don't think you need it. The only way would be to push the equals sign to the right in the first two conditions, which is bad.